# Capture Select and Deselect events in an edit control

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I have a form with a `TMemo` control where you can enter text, and another `TEdit` control that I want when the user selects text in Memo to be automatically displayed in Edit. Is there a way to do this without using a timer? (Actually, is there a way to capture an event that occurs when text is selected or canceled in the Memo control?)

I know that `OnMouseUp` and `OnKeyUp` events can be used, but in this way the Edit will only be updated after the user has finished selecting, and not at the time of selection.

Comment: `RichMemo` has `OnSelectionChange` event

Comment: Isn't there also an OnMouseMove Event?

Comment: @Eskandar You mean `TRichEdit` (`TRichMemo` is a third party component). It does work, but the component behavior is different from the regular `TMemo`. (It also does not have the Edit system menu.

Comment: @dummzeuch This will not help if a text is selected using the keyboard, for example. I'm also not sure that the MouseMove message is sent when the mouse is pressed.

Comment: I guess there is only one way: Handle several events for mouse (OnMouseMove, OnMouseDown) and keyboard (OnKeyDown) and in each call a method that checks for selected text.

Comment: @dummzeuch `TRichEdit` does handle such events while selecting and deselecting text, so it is possible (it only has a number of other drawbacks to use).

Answer (score 1):

This is my try and it works in most cases. Maybe you can adapt it and tweak it to your likings.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure Memo1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Memo1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure Memo1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure Memo1KeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    mouseselectionstarted: boolean;
    procedure FillText;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  System.UITypes;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FillText;
begin
  Edit1.Text := Memo1.SelText;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mouseselectionstarted := false;
end;

procedure TForm1.Memo1KeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (ssShift in Shift) and (Key in [vkLeft, vkUp, vkRight, vkDown]) then
    FillText;
end;

procedure TForm1.Memo1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if (Button = mbLeft) then
    mouseselectionstarted := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.Memo1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if mouseselectionstarted then
    FillText;
end;

procedure TForm1.Memo1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  mouseselectionstarted := false;
end;
```

Comment: I definitely appreciate the effort, although it is not really my preferred solution. Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate why?

Comment: The truth is that I have a specific goal to get the selected text separately as I write it, and to do that I need a less complex code in terms of event capture.
The code you suggest (I haven't checked, but probably) does the job, but requires handling 4 different events and updating a Boolean variable each time. It's a bit complex for my purpose. Anyway thanks for the thought and originality!